# Error C2440 and Error 4024

Tags: c

I am getting constant errors trying to call these two function for my program. As it is one of my first for class, I cannot figure out where it is going wrong. It should simply call the function grosscal and tax cal dependent on what pay rate you choice, using the switch case to cycle through the choices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BASEHRS 40 // hours at pay1
#define OVERTIME 1.5 // 1.5 time
#define AMT1 300 // 1st rate tier
#define AMT2 150 // 2st rate tier
#define RATE1 0.15 // rate for 1st tier
#define RATE2 0.20 // rate for 2nd tier
#define RATE3 0.25 // rate for 3rd tier

double grossCal(double, double, double);
double taxCal(double, double);
double netCal(double, double, double);

int main(void)
{
double hours, gross, net, taxes;
double pay1, pay2, pay3, pay4;
int payrate;
pay1 = 8.75;
pay2 = 9.33;
pay3 = 10.00;
pay4 = 11.20;

printf("Enter the number of hours worked this week: ");
scanf("%lf", &hours);

printf("*****************************************************************\n");
printf("Enter the number corresponding to the desired pay rate or action:\n");
printf("1) $%.2f/hr\t\t2) $%.2f/hr\n", pay1, pay2);
printf("3) $%.2f/hr\t\t4) $%.2f/h\n", pay3, pay4);
printf("5) quit\n");
printf("*****************************************************************\n");
scanf("%d", &payrate);

switch (payrate)
{
    case '1' :  grossCal(&gross, pay1, hours);
                taxCal(gross, &taxes);
                break;
    case '2' :  grossCal(&gross, pay2, hours);
                taxCal(gross, &taxes);
                break;
    case '3' :  grossCal(&gross, pay3, hours);
                taxCal(gross, &taxes);
                break;
    case '4' :  grossCal(&gross, pay4, hours);
                taxCal(gross, &taxes);
                break;
    default  :  break;
}

net = gross - taxes;
printf("gross: $%.2f; taxes: $%.2f; net: $%.2f\n", gross, taxes, net);
return 0;
}
double grossCal(double *grossPay, double pay, double hours){
    if (hours <= BASEHRS)
        *grossPay = hours * pay;
    else
        *grossPay = BASEHRS * pay + (hours - BASEHRS) * pay * OVERTIME;
}
double taxCal(double gross, double *taxestotal){
    if (gross <= AMT1)
        *taxestotal = gross * RATE1;
    else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
        *taxestotal = AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2;
    else
        *taxestotal = AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3;
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overfliow. Can you please tell us what the errors are? edit your question and add that as part of the question. Give us an example of what the input/output should be and what you're getting instead. Tel us which line is throwing the error, etc... anything more you can add to help us to help you will mean your problem gets solved the quicker.

Comment: Both functions should return a `double`, but their is no `return` statement. Or change their return type to `void`. Also change `case '1':` to `case 1:` and so on.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. *A specific problem or error* would include the **exact** error message you're receiving, and you're getting far more than two error numbers.

Comment: First argument to grossCal and 2nd argument of taxcal are conflecting .. while declearing you have decleared it as double but while calling you are passing double *

Comment: I think declaration should be `double grossCal(double*, double, double);` first parameter should be of pointer type. same as `double taxCal(double, double*);`

Comment: If you are not returning any value you can make your function of type `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You have mismatching function declarations, function calls, and function definitions.

*Declaration*

```
double grossCal(double, double, double);
double taxCal(double, double);
```

*Usage*

```
  case '1' :  grossCal(&gross, pay1, hours); // &gross is not double
              taxCal(gross, &taxes);         // &taxes is not double.
              break;
  case '2' :  grossCal(&gross, pay2, hours);
              taxCal(gross, &taxes);
              break;
  case '3' :  grossCal(&gross, pay3, hours);
              taxCal(gross, &taxes);
              break;
  case '4' :  grossCal(&gross, pay4, hours);
              taxCal(gross, &taxes);
```

*Implementation*

```
double grossCal(double *grossPay, double pay, double hours){
...

double taxCal(double gross, double *taxestotal){
...
```

Your usage and implementation match even though the functions don't return anything.

You can clean things up by:

**Minimal Changes**

*Change the declarations*

```
void grossCal(double*, double, double);
void taxCal(double, double*);
```

*Keep the current usage*

*Change the implementations*

```
void grossCal(double *grossPay, double pay, double hours){
...

void taxCal(double gross, double *taxestotal){
...
```

**Slightly More Change But Way Better**

*Interfaces*

```
// Return the gross pay
double grossCal(double pay, double hours);

// Return the taxes.
double taxCal(double);
```

*Usages*

Simplify it so that there is minimal duplicate code. Add a new variable
 called pay.

```
  case 1 :  pay = pay1;
            break;
  case 2 :  pay = pay2;
            break;
  case 3 :  pay = pay3;
            break;
  case 4 :  pay = pay4;
            break;
```

After the switch statement,

```
  gross = grossCal(pay, hour);
  taxes = taxCal(gross);
```

*Implementations*

```
double grossCal(double pay, double hours){
   if (hours <= BASEHRS)
      return (hours * pay);
   else
      return (BASEHRS * pay + (hours - BASEHRS) * pay * OVERTIME);
}

double taxCal(double gross){
   if (gross <= AMT1)
      return (gross * RATE1);
   else if (gross <= AMT1 + AMT2)
      return (AMT1 * RATE1 + (gross - AMT1) * RATE2);
   else
      return (AMT1 * RATE1 + AMT2 * RATE2 + (gross - AMT1 - AMT2) * RATE3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with cases.
As you are using

```
case '1' :  //Code
            break;
case '2' :  //Code
            break;
case '3' :  //Code
            break;
case '4' : //Code
            break;
```

Change this to

```
case 1 :  //Code
            break;
case 2 :  //Code
            break;
case 3 :  //Code
            break;
case 4 : //Code
            break;
```

because `payrate` is a integer variable.
Change your function declaration like this:

```
void grossCal(double*, double, double);  //make it void and 1st parameter should be of pointer type. 
void taxCal(double, double*);  //make it void type and 2nd parameter should be of pointer type.
```